# How to switch to the day calendar with iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I recently switched an iPhone from iOS 6 to iOS 7.1.2.
Within iOS 6 I was using Calendar on the day display and week display mode continuously. It was easy to a point I can't even recall how I did this switching (we should take notes when we see an interface which is working nicely).

With iOS 7.1.2 I have a serious interface problem.

Within `Calendar` I am able to switch from an annual view to a month view with the `month name` topleft red button. I discovered that I can also switch back to the month view by clicking on the `month name` red header.
But I can't see any way to switch to a day or week view.
On the bottom left corner I have a `Today` red button, but it doesn't do anything.

What is the intelligent method to access the actual day calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle from month to week view, turn the phone sideways.

Day view is dependant on whether or not you have the list view on or off [highlighted in blue] If that's on, the day's events appear underneath the month. If it's off, tapping a day will take you to that day's view.

Once in Day view, the same button will then toggle between single day & list of upcoming events view.

**Month view**
[image: Month View]

---

**Week view**
 [image: Week view]

---

**Day view**
[image: Day view]

---

**Event list**
[image: Event list]

Comment: Thank you. I have the week one :)! Now for the day Calendar, do I have to rotate it around another axe?

Comment: Day view is just the list under Month (the bit I scribbled out) - toggled by the icon in red on my first picture. Other than that, it's on your notifications drop-down.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't "see" how to get the day Calendar. If you click on the `Today` button do you get to the Calendar of today? On my iOS 7.1.2, this button seems "dead".

Comment: ach - my bad - updating answer. I've only just found it myself...

Comment: I understood my blindness :). The day circled of red isn't just an emphasis of today. It is also a **button**. On the other hand the red `Today` isn't a button at all, it's just **emphasis**. I feel this confusion between emphasis and function isn't a real improvement. It looks like a nice confusion :(.

Comment: BTW, thank you. Now I can exit of my "month view jail", even if I still don't see it (wrong interface design).

Comment: I didn't like it to start with - but I guess it's just one of those things I got used to - so much so that actually I no longer look at the day view, I just use the list underneath Month.