# How can I see a list of events in one specific calendar?

Tags: ios, macos, calendar, ical

Using the built-in OS X calendar application. I've got events broken down by general, school, friends, concerts, etc.

How can I, for instance, see just my concert listings? I don't mean go to the menu bar and turn off all the other calendars, which in and of itself is an awful interface having to individually click on each button.  I mean I want to open a separate window with a list showing the date, and event, in chronological order.  So I can see what my concert itinerary is for the year.  (Or any other event, just using concerts as an example.)

For bonus points -- is this doable in iOS with the built-in iOS calendar app?

Comment: for bonus points… ;) see my answer at http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177898/85275 for how to get to the event list in iOS. You'd still have to uncheck the other calendars, though, to see just one

Answer (score 3):

typing a "." into the search field and pressing enter will bring up a chronological list of events.

As far as sorting by calendar, I think the only way is to de-select the other calendars and then do the search.

Comment: Thank you.  The "." in search -- while wildly unintuitive -- worked perfectly.  Much appreciated!